# Java Log4J Logger Messages

Tags: java, log4j

I am working on log4j with Java. I am redirecting all my applications logger messages to a specific folder inside my project like this:

```
logs/log4j-MyFirstClass.log
```

If I want to redirect specific file messages to specific log file, for ex: ABC.java logger messages to ABC.log file, then how should I change this log4J.properties file ? Please help. Here is my log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}   %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/log4j-MyFirstClass.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an appender for each file, then specify which packages use which appender.

```
# Root logger option; everything logs to console at debug
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Classes in package com.foo.bar will use the file1 appender
log4j.logger.com.foo.bar=file1

# Classes in package com.whizz.bang will use the file2 appender, note we also overrode the default log level
log4j.logger.com.whizz.bang=DEBUG, file2

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}   %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Appender for file 1
log4j.appender.file1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file1.File=logs/log4j-first.log
log4j.appender.file1.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file1.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Appender for file 2
log4j.appender.file2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file2.File=logs/log4j-second.log
log4j.appender.file2.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file2.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. I will work on this and let you know.

Comment: I am getting some issue: log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.log4j-MediaCenter.log

Comment: This is log4j file modified:    # Classes in package ro.ibm.emm.kaltura will use the file2 appender
log4j.logger.ro.ibm.emm.kaltura=DEBUG,log4j-MediaCenter.log      log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/log4j-MediaCenter.log